# IdentityServer4 discovery document returns 404 when deployed to a subroute behind a reverse proxy

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I need to change the url of a discovery endpoint from this:

```
/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

to this:

```
/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

i'm trying to deploy ID4 to Azure Kubernetes Service. It all works out great when i deploy ID4 to the root address (like http://xxxx.europe.cloudapp.azure.com) - I see the welcome page and i can access my discovery endpoint.

However, when i deploy ID4 to a subroute (http://xxxx.europe.cloudapp.azure.com/identity) i can't access oidc-configuration.   I'm using URL rewriting so when i click the link to access discovery document (http://xxxx.europe.cloudapp.azure.com/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration) i get HTTP404.

EDIT:

when i add:

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.PathBase = "/identity";
        await next.Invoke();
    });
```

all css/js/jpeg files are loaded correctly. This is progress.

However when i click the link visible on a welcome page ((http://xxxx.europe.cloudapp.azure.com/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration) i get HTTP404. When i click grants ((http://xxxx.europe.cloudapp.azure.com/identity/grants). It's the same story. Removing "/identity" manually from link still leads to 404.

Comment: did try the my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
app.Map("/identity", authApp =>
{
    app.UseStaticFiles("/identity");
    authApp.UsePathBase(new PathString("/identity"));
    authApp.UseIdentityServer();
});
}
```

- Github issues

  - [can't reach discovery endpoint after deploying IS4 to a subroute · Issue #2920 · IdentityServer/IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2920)

Edit :

also try not to use

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection()
```

leave the HTTPS for the proxy sever

Comment: It works locally this way, but it doesn't work on Azure Kubernetes Service for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use relative URI's by using `Map` Api on the `IApplicationBuilder`.

```
        app.Map("/identity", authApp =>
        {
            authApp.UseIdentityServer();
        });
```

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately, it still returns 404

Comment: @skyrunner Can you try `app.Use(async (context, next) => { context.Request.Path = "/identity" + context.Request.Path; await next.Invoke(); });` ? This is a hack, I don't know if it will work. Use this middleware before `app.UseIdentityServer()`.

Comment: First off, thanks for your help. This didn't work as well - with this code even the welcome page doesn't appear. I hoped there is maybe a IS4 property i can control the discovery endpoint url with. But i can't find such setting anywhere in docs.

Comment: @skyrunner There isn't a property. Look at this code https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Hosting/EndpointRouter.cs That's where I got idea to use `Map` and changing `context.Request.Path`. You should try to understand why this endpoint routing doesn't work for you. I've just tried to host locally on IIS as a web app and it worked for me using `Map`.

Comment: @skyrunner Also, do other endpoints work (like connect/token) before you tried to make these changes? Is it just disco page which returns NotFound?

Comment: your solution indeed works in local environment. So far i still can't force it to work on Azure Kubernetes Service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vidmantas and Mohamed answers i managed to make it work. I used their advices and here's what made it work in the end for me:

```
         app.Map("/identity", authApp =>
        {
            authApp.UseStaticFiles();
            authApp.UseIdentityServer();
            authApp.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        });
```

Somehow it didn't work right without

> authApp.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

I had some issues in my istio gateway configuration. After solving them IS4 works like a charm in a subroute. Thank you guys for your answers.